# Shell-Script Logging

Tags: shell, unix, logging, output

i want to implement a shell-script that runs the command `xyz` and stores its output in a variable, but at the *same* time forwarding the commands output to the shell-scripts stdout.

This is because I want to launch this script via `launchd`, let it automatically log the script's output, but then also let the script push the individual commands output to the web. The script should not simply buffer the commands output and print it after it ran, but rather in real time.

Is something like this possible, and if, how do you implement it?

Thanks

thel30n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to save log into a shell variable and avoid buffering command's output at the same time. But the alternative way would be saving log messages to a file using `tee(1)`. For example:

```
LOGFILE=/path/to/logfile
run_and_log() {
    $@ | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
}

run_and_log xyz
```

Comment: I may actually ending up doing this. It would have been nice to use `launchd` to log, but your solution may be the only possible for my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for the command:

```
$VAR=$(echo 'test' | tee /dev/tty)
test

echo $VAR
test
```

Comment: However, the message "test" has not appeared on the stdout when running first line.

Comment: This is probably the right answer but technically this doesn't write output to stdout as the poster wanted.

Comment: yes you are right, but i think it works for his problem

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it does not work, as `launchd` requires logs to be posted to stdout. If there really is no other method to do something like this, I think, that I may need to use the tee-command to log directly, which definitely wouldn't be as nice as using `launchd` for this.